# info needed on "Take Screenshot" keyword to take screen shot of remote machine

Tags: robotframework

how to take screen shot of a remote machine. Robot Framework runs on host machine. system under test is a remote machine. I have tried using remote server given in Robot Framework itself but the keyword "Take Screenshot" is taking screenshot of host and not remote desktop.

I am able to successfully take screen sheet of the remote desktop using a user defined keyword which in turn using a third part tool screenshot.exe as explained below ... my preference is to use inbuilt keyword "Take Screenshot"

"Remote Screenshot" is the user defined keyword that I used. This keyword in turn uses third party tool screenshot.exe.

The corresponding python script along with the robot framework script is given below . Following is the python script which runs on remote server, as a prerequisite , this script needs to be launched first on the remote server and then start robot framework.

```
#begin python script
import subprocess
class ExampleRemoteLibrary(object):
    """Example library to be used with Robot Framework's remote server.
     """
    def remote_screenshot(self):
        subprocess.call([r'C:\rg\screenshot.exe','-o',r'C:\rg\screenshot.png'], shell = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer
    RobotRemoteServer(ExampleRemoteLibrary(), host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx')

#end python script
```

following is the robot framework script.

```
#begin script
*** Settings ***
Library       Remote    http://${ADDRESS}:${PORT}
Library    Screenshot

*** Variables ***
${ADDRESS}    xx.xx.xx.xx
${PORT}       8270

*** Test Cases ***
    Take Screenshot
    Remote Screenshot
#end script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to do it the way you are thinking.

The only way the standard `Take Screenshot` keyword would work on a remote host is setting up a [remote library interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#remote-library-interface), which you have done. After this you would need to define a new screenshot keyword on the remote host, and use that keyword, you will be unable to use local keywords on a remote host.

I would probably not bother with remote library interface to begin with, and instead install the [SSHLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html) and use that to run terminal commands on the remote host.